# asp.net mvc dropdownlist with sample date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I am trying to mock a dropdownlist with no data and just "select" text. How to do that?

I tried this

```
@Html.DropDownList("",new List<SelectListItem>(),"Select")
```

I know it should be some thing similar to

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.sampleList, "Select")
```

but I am not interacting with controller as I am UI designer. How can I change my code?

Comment: Why use helper methods if it's just for a mockup? You could just use plain HTML.

Comment: They need HTML form to get a formcollection. I dont have other option than this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it correct. However, you need to provide the name of the field:

```
@Html.DropDownList("NameOfField", new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select")
```